# 2-8 K&R C Exercise whats wrong?

Tags: c

I'm doing that exercise

> write a function rightrot(x,n) that return the value of the integer x rotated to the right by n bit positions.

but when I try to run it I don't get what I expect.

```
#include"stdio.h"    
int most_signficant_bit(unsigned x){
        int bitpos;
        for(bitpos = -1; x!=0;++bitpos){
            x=x>>1;
        }
        return bitpos;
    }
unsigned rightrot(unsigned x, unsigned n){
        int bitpos;
        bitpos  = most_signficant_bit(x);

       x = ((x>>n)|(((~(~0<<n))&x)<<(bitpos-n)));
        return x;
    }
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        unsigned int c1;
        c1 = 0xff1;

        printf("bitfield  %x "
        " after rightrot %x \n",c1, rightrot(c1, 4) );
        return 0;
    }
```

I know that `(x>>n)`moves the bitfield 'n' times to the right `0000 1111 1111` to copy the 'n' less significant bits from that space.

`(~(~0<<n))&x)` copy the n less significant bits(`1111 1111 0001` & `0000 0000 1111` = `0000 0000 0001`) and then move these bits to the correct place 
`<<(bitpos-n)` and after with or copy those bits in `x`.

But I got `0xff` instead `0x1ff` or in binary `0000 1111 1111` instead `0001 1111 1111`.

so what is wrong?

Comment: funny, when I execute the code I get `ff` not `8ff` or `1ff`.

Comment: yeap, 0x8ff is when i put <<(bitpos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 x = ((x>>n)|(((~(~0<<n))&x)<<(bitpos-n)));
```

Don't you think instead of this it should be

```
 x = ((x>>n)|(((~(~0<<n))&x)<<(bitpos-n+1)));
```

Comment: Exactly, I almost wrote the same answer.. But you were a min faster +1

Answer (score 0):

I think that this expression

```
x = ((x>>n)|(((~(~0<<n))&x)<<(bitpos-n+1)));
```

is too complicated and unreadable.:)

Moreover the function implementation that uses this expression is invalid because n can be gretaer than the number of bits in an object of type unsigned int.

The function can be written the following way as shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int rotate_right( unsigned int x, size_t n )
{
    const size_t N = CHAR_BIT * sizeof( int );

    n %= N;

    return x >> n | x << ( N - n );
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int x = 0x12345678;

    size_t n = CHAR_BIT * sizeof( int );

    do 
    { 
        printf( "%x\n", x ); 
        x = rotate_right( x, CHAR_BIT / 2 );
    } while ( n -= CHAR_BIT / 2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
12345678
81234567
78123456
67812345
56781234
45678123
34567812
23456781
```

You can remove header `<limits.h>` and count the number of bits in an object of type `unsigned int` using the following function

```
size_t bit_count()
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = ~0u; i; i >>= 1 ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: yep, this is another way to do this exercise, but in k&r only uses stdio.h untill this chapter

Comment: @warrior It is not a problem. You can replace CHAR_BIT with 8 and remove the header.:) Or you can use your own function most_signficant_bit that to count the total number of bits in an object of type unsigned iint. In any case the final function can be written as I showed.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer, your way its smartest i need to learn the standard library.